# Calling a Spring controller from itself based on the response

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

We have a requirement where...when we get a request to our controller we make a call to another api and based on the other api response we have to retrigger the request to controller with different parameter

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public Map<String, Account> searchEndpoint(@RequestParam(name = "query", required = true) String query) {

        RequestPayload req = new RequestPayload(query);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = http.executeSecurePost(this.searchUrl, req, SearchResponse.class);

        if(("particularModel").equalsIgnoreCase(searchResponse.getModel()))
        {
              String  differentQueryParameter = searchResponse.getName();
              searchEndpoint(differentQueryParameter);
        } 
        else {
             //do something else
        }
        return json response;

}
```

when i do like this ...it's working fine where it's making the second call and getting the new response and returns ...but again a third query where this time is the original query get's fired. Not sure why the third query is fired. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use a while or do-while loop. But you might loop forever if you did not get a "particularModel". call the same `executeSecurePost` and do not call your controller recursively.

Comment: Why not ...i don't see a reason not to

Answer (score 1):

calling your handler again and again it may result in a recursive function. you  could avoid this kind of programming .you put the logic for calling the api  in service method and do it .

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")public Map<String, Account> searchEndpoint(@RequestParam(name = "query", required = true) String query) {
  //put this logic in service
  RequestPayload req = new RequestPayload(query);
  SearchResponse searchResponse = http.executeSecurePost(this.searchUrl, req, SearchResponse.class);

    if(("particularModel").equalsIgnoreCase(searchResponse.getModel()))
    {
          String  differentQueryParameter = searchResponse.getName();
          //put this logic in service and just call it
          RequestPayload req = new RequestPayload(query);
          SearchResponse searchResponse = http.executeSecurePost(this.searchUrl, req, SearchResponse.class)
    } 
    else {
         //do something else
    }
    return json response;

}
```

Comment: Not sure could you please explain the reason why it shouldn't be done